# ¿Cómo acceder al grupo de un usuario desde una clase Manager utilizando en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Lo que pretendo es que los usuarios solo puedan ver los documentos asociados a su grupo en el panel de administración.

Lo que hice fue crear un **proxy model** que hereda de la clase **Documento** y por medio de una clase **Manager** (`DocumentManager`) le puse un filtro para el grupo, pero de momento está estático (`.filter(grupo_gestion=2)`), la idea es que sea dinámico de acuerdo al usuario que tenga la sesión activa pero no he podido acceder al grupo.

Intente lo siguiente sin resultado:

```
 .filter(grupo_gestion=request.user.groups.all())
```

Archivo `managers.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class DocumentManager(models.Manager):        
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DocumentManager,self).get_queryset().filter(grupo_gestion=2)
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Documento(models.Model):
    fecha_creacion =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)#(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_modificado = models.DateTimeField('Modificado', auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    #autor = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    titulo = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    descripcion = models.CharField('Descripción', max_length = 500, blank = False, null = False)
    contenido = RichTextUploadingField('Edición del documento', blank=False, null=True)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/Documentos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grupo_gestion = models.ForeignKey (Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class DocumentProxy(Documento):
    objects=DocumentManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.autor=request.user
        super().save_model(request,obj, form,change)

admin.site.register(Documento, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(DocumentProxy)
```

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, quieres que los documentos se asocien a un grupo en especifico, al igual que el usuario (que seria una mala idea) o que en base al grupo en el que esta el usuario se muestren ciertos documentos?

Comment: la segunda, que en base al grupo en el que está el usuario se muestren ciertos documentos. De hecho ya "funciona" solo que por defecto yo lo estoy dando un id de grupo, en este caso el grupo con id=2 ( `return super(DocumentManager,self).get_queryset().filter(grupo_gestion=2))` porque no he podido acceder al grupo al que pertenece ese usuario para que sea dinámico, como dije lo intente  con -> `return super(DocumentManager,self).get_queryset().filter(grupo_gestion=request.user.groups.all())`

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo necesario crear un *Proxy Model* en este caso, puedes simplemente modificar el QuerySet de todas las instancias del modelo, que el sitio de administración puede editar. Sobrescribiendo el método [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) del `ModelAdmin` del modelo:

```
@admin.register(Documento)
class DocumentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)

        # Iteramos todos los grupos del usuario
        for group in request.user.groups.all():
            # Si el nombre del grupo es tal, pues retornamos un queryset deacuerdo 
            # a dicho grupo
            if group.name == 'grupo_que_evita_modificar_los_documentos_del_usuario_pepe':
                return queryset.exclude(autor__username = 'pepe')

            # Si el nombre del grupo es tal, pues retornamos un queryset deacuerdo 
            # a dicho grupo
            if group.name == 'grupo_x'
                return queryset.filter(...)

        # Si los grupos del usuario no limita la edicion de los ciertos documentos, pues
        # retornamos todos los documentos
        return queryset
```

Y listo, en **base a cierto grupo, muestras ciertos registros, documentos o instancias** en el sitio de administración.

Cabe recalcar que el propósito de los grupos **es asignar ciertos permisos a ciertos usuarios**, no esto, aunque me parece valido hacerlo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Tenías razón, no era necesario utilizar un Proxy Model, simplemente con modificar el método get_queryset() del modelo Admin funciona, gracias